# Why is there no overall interference pattern with a delayed choice quantum eraser?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-eraser

Consider a delayed choice quantum eraser:

[image: Delayed choice quantum eraser]

There is an interference pattern at D<sub>1</sub>. There is an interference pattern at D<sub>2</sub>. There is no interference pattern at either D<sub>3</sub> or D<sub>4</sub>.

I also understand there is no overall interference pattern (if you count all photons regardless of which detector has been hit), and the question is, why?

The total pattern would be a sum of patterns at D<sub>1</sub>, D<sub>2</sub>, D<sub>3</sub> and D<sub>4</sub>. If there is no overall interference pattern, it means interference patterns at D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub> cancel each other. Why does it happen?

The shape of an interference pattern is determined by the geometry and the wavelength, and both are the same at D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub>. So why are interference patterns at D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub> different at all?

Comment: My question looks similar to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/350945/interference-pattern-in-delayed-choice-quantum-eraser, but that question does not address interference patterns at D1 and D2 canceling each other.

Comment: If I correctly read the optical scheme,- $D_3, D_4$ is reached by photons only from 1 slit,- hence no interference. $D_1,D_2$ , which by the way has mirror symmetry between optical paths along to them,- are reached by photons from both slits and hence interferes.

Answer (score 2):

Only when two things contribute to exactly the same wave function can there be
interference. Because the two paths for the traveling electrons are now entangled with the recording electrons, the left and right paths are distinguishable, so no interference pattern is seen as shown below;

[image]

Comment: Travelling photons. Not electrons.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, we are talking about coincidences with D0 in all cases (D1/D2/D3/D4). See https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9903047 for the underlying experiment by Kim et al.

See figures 3 and 4, which show the D1 and D2 outcomes. I would not say "D1 and D2 cancel each other" as you do.

The reason they are different (as you ask) is effectively like saying: "D1 shows a pattern for the left slit, D2 shows the pattern for the right slit". That is not technically accurate, but it captures the spirit.  They are but essentially simply mirror images of each other - i.e. otherwise the same.