# Why doesn't the interference pattern at D0 alter the probabilities of D1 or D2 in the delayed choice quantum eraser experiment? Or does it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment

I was reading the answer of Hypnosifl on [What's wrong with this experiment showing that either FTL communication is possible or complementarity doesn't hold?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/120164/whats-wrong-with-this-experiment-showing-that-either-ftl-communication-is-possi)
[image]

If we assume that:

- Alice is at D1/2/3/4 and replaces BSA and BSB with mirrors (so we always lose the 'which-path-information')
- Bob is at D0 and makes his measurement first

Now let's say Bob sees his photon landing right in the middle of his screen, why doesn't this alter the probabilities of the entangled photon ending up in D1/2? It seems from the interference patterns that in the case of photons landing in the middle of the screen there is a much stronger correlation with D1 than D2 (maybe 90%/10%).

[image]

So basically the question is why is P(D1) = P(D1|D0)? Or isn't it?